# RaycastHit.collider returns null but Physics.Raycast returns true. (Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a raycast to detect when there is an object withing 5 units of the player, and it should return the name of the collider. This code returns a NullReferenceException. I have checked and the Physics.Raycast returns true if I am looking at an object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grapple : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public RaycastHit hit;
    public float distance = 5f;
    //public GameObject line;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * distance, Color.red);
        //Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), distance);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
                Debug.Log(hit.collider.);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How does your code return the hit object? Your code doesn't return the collider which it hit, it just returns either `true` when the collision is detected or `false` when it doesn't. To get the reference to the object that this raycast hit, do this:

```cs
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out RaycastHit hit, 5))
{
    Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
}
```

The raycast returns `true` when there's any collision within the range and it even returns the collision object.

Comment: sorry I am so stupid. I edited it to test and forgot to undo it back to the code that had issues but I will try what you said.
Edit: I just tried it and it worked! Thank you so much!